# PHP how to get the string from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

AJAX CODE

```
$.post("test.php",'aaaaa',function(data){alert(data);});
```

test.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

why i finally get an empty array?PHP how to get the string from ajax?

Comment: $.post("test.php",{data: 'aaaaa'},function(data){alert(data);});

Comment: try a:'aaaaa' and not 'aaaaa' directly, do give a name to the datas

Comment: Read the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 $.post( "test.php", { name: "test" })
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
      });

print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case I will suggest you to send using the following method

```
                   $.ajax({
                        data:"mystring=aaaaa"
                        method:"POST",
                        url:"test.php",
                        success:function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
```

Note it is just an example.hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is :

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
$( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Details : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/